# Git bare repository on remote server

Tags: wordpress, git, repository, git-pull

I have a web server with ssh access where I show my customers the preview of their WordPress website. On that Server, I create a git repository for each customer (example: xyz-website.com.git). I run "git init --bare" so I have a repository. Then, I create a hook (post-receive) where I set the git-dir and working-dir. So when I create a Website locally, I can push to that repository and the Website becomes available so the customer can check it.

Problem: When the customer decides to install plugins, there will be new files on the server. My Idea was whenever I need to code something for that website, I just "git pull". Which doesnt work.

Can anyone tell my why and how to solve my problem?

Comment: "Which doesnt work." why? Is there some common files between the ones created by the plugins and the ones pulled from the repo?

Comment: That was just an example.

If I create a new file at the working dir on the server, for example named "testfile.txt", it is not being downloaded when I locally do "git pull". Because the repository doesnt know about the new file.

Comment: Would it be possible for the client to ad those files in their own copy of the repo and push? (instead of accessing directly the remote working dir on the server?)

Comment: No I guess not. :( I hoped to be able to fetch the newest files with git pull. Doesnt seem like someone has a solution for it. I dont see what git pull is used for then? Or is my repository configured the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the wp-content/plugins/ folder is included in your .gitignore file. If it is there, remove it.

For more information, refer this URL: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

Comment: The link you posted is EXACTLY what I have. And its working fine. BUT: What if someone creates files on the VPS/Webserver? For example, someone installs a plugin on the live website. The next time I develop locally I would want to "git pull" from the VPS so I have the current data! But exatcly this doesnt work! Because they are bare repositories. I'm looking for a solution for that.

Comment: You need to installed it to your local machine manually. There is no other solution.

Comment: Thats sad. Is there another way of deplyoing that you would recommend then?